# Is it possible to switch two regions of the screen (Windows)?

Tags: python, windows, accessibility

I am a developer with low vision.  Right now I am working on a personal project to improve my ability to make use of large screens and play video games.

Sometimes when using a widescreen monitor up close (within 4-8 inches) I have trouble reading the screen along the edges.  This is particularly troublesome when trying to read the clock or use a mini map in a game.  It would be nice if I could temporarily switch the edge of the screen with the center.

I have successfully been able to move parts of the screen using screen captures and PyQt ([screenshot](https://github.com/frodopwns/screenflip/blob/master/screenshot.png)). 
This is nice but I would like to do this while preserving my ability to click or select text in the region.  This seems like a rather involved process If I want to use PyQt and somehow pass clicks through to the screen.

For example:

[image]

Is there a lower level api that would allow me to tinker with the screen's output?  Any suggestions are welcome!

Thanks

Comment: I don't know, so I'll just throw ideas out: Do you use a full screen magnifier, like the Windows 7 and newer Magnifier, where only a part of the screen around the mouse cursor is visible at once and moving the mouse cursor pans the screen? (I do.) I don't know of any that lets you push edges to the center of the screen by keeping the mouse at dead center (maybe the GNOME 3 one does? I have to check); I'm wondering how badly that ouwld break things if done on Windows...

Comment: In windows I use a tool called Zoomit (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897434.aspx). IT is free and better than the magnifier imo.  I don't think it would ideal for full screen game situations tho.